# Use response object from one request in body of another [postman]

Tags: postman

In one request I have the following:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody)
postman.setGlobalVariable("myData", data.myData)
```

I'm looking to include this `myData` in the request body for another request.

The body for that request looks something like this:

```
{
  "myData": "{{myData}}"
}
```

However this does not work. The global is set to `[object Object]` and that string gets sent to the server in the request body instead of the actual object.

Is there a way to attach this `globals[myData]` object to the request body in `Pre-request Script`? Something like the following?

```
requestBody.myData = globals[myData]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things should fix this for you:

1. remove the quotes around the `{{myData}}` variable in your post body
2. stringify the `myData` variable

It should look like this in your test:

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("myData", JSON.stringify(data.myData))
```

And this in your body

```
{
  "myData": {{myData}}
}
```